# column-wise f, F, t, T

Tags: cursor-motions

Sometimes, I need to delete until a character up or down the same column.

Consider a file with the following content:

```
abc
def
hij
```

When cursor is on `b`, doing a column-wise `dfi` should remove characters `b`, `e` and `i`. That means only the 1-character-width column of characters should be deleted.

Is it possible to do column-wise find and till?

Comment: Should only the 1-character-width column of characters be deleted, or all text in between the current cursor position and the target character in the same column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`vim-columnmove`](https://github.com/machakann/vim-columnmove) plugin and visual-mode block-wise selection to do this. The plugin imitates various groups of motions, and in this case:

> ## columnmove-f
>
> ---
>
> columnmove-f and its variants are the commands for bringing cursor to the position assigned by a character in the same column.
>
> This group has six keymappings, that is, `columnmove-f`,
>   `columnmove-t`, `columnmove-F`, `columnmove-T`, `columnmove-;`,
>   `columnmove-,`. Each of them are the imitations of `f`, `t`, `F`, `T`,
>   `;`, `,` commands, but work in vertical direction.

The motions are mapped to `<M-f/F/t/F>` by default, but since those combinations were interpreted as something else in my case, I used `<Leader>`:

```
map <leader>f <Plug>(columnmove-f)
map <leader>F <Plug>(columnmove-F)
map <leader>t <Plug>(columnmove-t)
map <leader>T <Plug>(columnmove-T)
```

Then, by pressing `d<C-v>\ti`, I could delete the characters `b`, and `e`. Without block visual mode, it deletes the first and second lines.

Comment: `columnmove-f` may be remapped in order to achieve things like `d<m-f>i` to delete along the column until the `i` character. I.e., one can do `omap <m-f>  <c-v><plug>(columnmove-f)` (and similar for the other motions). I find this to be quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

To quickly do this without the need for plugins:

```
<C-v>/i<cr>x
```

`<C-v>` to enter column mode

`/i<cr>` to search for i

`x` to delete the visually selected block

Comment: This works great when "i" is the only character between cursor and the target. Consider: `abci\nhij`, when cursor in on `b`. two search for `i` is necessary to get to the target character since search is linewise.

Comment: If you want to "delete from the current position to the next instance of i on another line starting on the current column" then just stick a j after the <C-v>.